# How to solve dropdown menu not showing -select-?

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

```
<fieldset class=\\"form-group col-md-6\\"\>

<label class=\\"required\\" for=\\"organization_name\\"\>Organization\</label\>                                 \<select class=\\"form-control select2\\" style=\\"width: 100%\\" name=\\"organization_name\\" required\>           <option value=\\"\\"\>" . OPTION_SELECT . "\</option\>";

$organizations = organization::all();

foreach ($organizations as $o) :

selected = ($organization_name === $o-\>organization_name) ? " selected" : "";                          $modal .= "\<option value=\\"$o-\>organization_name\\"$selected\>$o-\>organization_name\</option\>";            endforeach;

$modal .= "

</select\>

</fieldset\>
```

The above code is selecting a list of organisations from the database and showing as a dropdown on the form. But the default option value is supposed to be -select- but its showing nothing as a default value.

I tried several other ways to wrote the same code, but no change

Comment: Please show the code properly formatted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `selected = ...` is missing a `$`

Comment: "_As you can see in the picture ..._" There is no picture

Comment: Missing `<?php` before `$organizations = ...`